# Detect trending "reactions" (one or more) in an article (Like Buzzfeed and others)

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have a reactions vote system to "tag" my articles with things like: LOL, WTF, OMG, and so on...

I would like to know what would be the best solution to detect what "reactions" are "trending" in that article.

For example: http://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/pug-stroller-and-a-baby it,s tagged with WIN, 
CUTE, LOL

[image: Tagged with WIN, CUTE, LOL]

With this votes:

[image]

But this one: http://www.buzzfeed.com/daves4/11-animals-having-their-hearts-tickled-out

Is only tagged as CUTE

[image]

Because the diference between CUTE and the others options is pretty big, regardless of the number of votes itself.

[image]

**I already have the votes for each reaction in my database... So...**

**I would like to know what would be the best way (php or mysql query?) to detect what are the most important reactions...**

**I'm using PHP and MySQL**

Thanks!

Comment: If the PHP aspect removed, it could be a very good question on Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are going to do this is utterly personal - that is, it will reflect your way of analyzing the responses. For instance, I don't think that the first example deserves the tag WIN (but that is only my opinion, of course).

I would try using fuzzy logic. You can define the fuzzy sets according to the percentage of votes and define your rules according to them. The best inherent quality of this solution is that you can fine tune your rule base in order to perform the analysis according to your desires.

If you are not familiar with fuzzy sets, the triangular set is the simpler one and is simply a line going from the lower limit to the maximum and another descending line from the maximum to the upper limit of the set (check an example [here](http://www.graco.unb.br/alvares/DOUTORADO/omega.enm.unb.br/pub/doutorado/disco2/ai.iit.nrc.ca/IR_public/fuzzy/fuzzyJDocs/FuzzySet.html)).

The fuzzy rules can be defined ad hoc, according to your thinking. For instance:
IF percentage is VERY HIGH then trending is HIGH
IF percentage is LOW then trending is LOW.

Afterwards, you can defuzzify your "trending" conclusion and establish a cutting limit in order to define whether or not there is a trend to that element.

It might seem a bit overwhelming, but the implementation is straightforward (a quick search in the internet made me find [this site](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Scientific-Engineering-Ruby/Controls-and-Systems-Modeling/Fast-Fuzzy-Implementation-32708.html)) and you will have a powerful tool available for whathever posterior use you may find.