# algorithm to select right categories based on statistics how users categorized items

Tags: php, algorithm

i have a system with limited set of categories (around 20). each user can assign those categories to items withing system (let's call this `user categories`). now i would like to introduce so called `system categories` - those woud be categories assigned to item based on statistic how users categorized it. the problem am i facing is how to choose right categories in following situations:

```
item 1
cat A - 10 users
cat B - 7 users
cat C - 1 users
cat D - 0 users
```

in above should `system categories` for item 1 be: A or AB or ABC ?

or another situation:

```
item 2
cat A - 10 users
cat B - 10 users
cat C - 10 users
cat D - 5 users
```

EDIT:
after browsing SO i think this could be solved using Roulette Wheel Selection Genetic Algorithm

Comment: What do you mean with "how users categorized it"?

Comment: you want something like suggesting the user the item categorization based on other user selection?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question in [Detect trending "reactions" (one or more) in an article (Like Buzzfeed and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366837/detect-trending-reactions-one-or-more-in-an-article-like-buzzfeed-and-other/11369635#11369635), stating that I would use fuzzy logic on that.

I would just like to make it clear to you that genetic algorithms are an optimization method that uses operators that mimic evolution (reproduction and mutation, mainly) and roulete wheel is a technique used to select the current solution on whom those operators will be applied. Even though genetic algorithms have been used to classification problems, I believe they are not whhat you are seeking at this time.

I think that you might have been confused by the usage of the term "selection", but I don't believe that neither genetic algorithms nor its selection techniques apply here.